# Which is the released version of Lucene.NET that supports .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Is there a released version (not Beta) of Lucene.NET that supports .NET 6.0?
If no, pls let me know when its likely to be released.
I see that Lucene.NET 4.8.0 Beta version supports .NET 6.0, but is a Beta version.

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no version as you can see in github. Why not to use the beta? You just can make use of the nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/4.8.0-beta00016

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.0.3 is a release version but it does not support .NET Core or .NET 6.0

Lucene.NET 4.8 DOES support .NET Core and .NET 6.0 but as you are aware, it's still in Beta (Beta16!).

The primary reason that it's still in Beta is that method signatures may change for a very small number of methods as the code continues to be refined.

You might find this recent issue helpful: [When is the release version planned?](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/437).

The bottom line is that we don't have a hard date, we'll get there when we get there.  That said, Lucene.NET 4.8 is extremely stable, is already used in production by several companies, has 7800+ passing unit tests and is clearly production worthy right now in my mind. YMMV.